# how to set a column which accepts null but not empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to develop a table in which I want the column should accept null keyword but column cannot be empty.

Comment: Just to clarify, the value can be NULL, '495', or 'greensleeves', just as long as it's not ''?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't do that through SQL Create table level. You'll need a front end function or a Trigger in DB that looks for the data being inserted and forces this column to not be ' '